# Access MS SQL from Php 5.5

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, ubuntu

I am using Php to connect the SQL server using these code:

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($server,$username,$password);
     or die("Could not connect to SQL server");
$selected = mssql_select_db($database,$dbcon)
     or die("Could not open database $database");
```

However, I found that the code does not run. No error message and cannot do any mssql_query() with this.

After some research, I found that mssql is not default supported by Php 5.5 like mysql. However, I do not find the sulotion.

I found this from Microsoft but they are for Php on Windows. I cannot find the one for Linux

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

What should I do to install the SQL driver for PHP 5.5 in Ubuntu.

**My Server**
PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu
SQL server 2012 on Microsoft server 2012R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the reference  for connecting to a MSSQL Server database wtih LAMP.

[Microsoft-SQL-Server-Database

Ubuntu Server – Connect to MSSQL via PHP](http://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/ubuntu-server-connect-to-mssql-via-php.html)

Its work on my PC.